# Google sheets unique if duplicates are egual to

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to display such numbers of locations where the location number is associated with the model where the condition is that from the list of locations it is checked whether there are only models named A in the given location.

I tried to use =UNIQUE(IF or Filter) but it also gives locations with other models.

Model A in the worksheet appears under three names and I would like to urge you to use the formula under several conditions of the name.

EDIT 1) I want to do a list where Location number is on this list only when all duplicates from location number they are compatible with the model.

For example,
when i want to this on example from img, list shoud be looks like 1 and 4.
Because in location 1 and 4 there are only models of device 1 and no other
[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55008423/edit) to give us the expected output?

Comment: I explained it better

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, B:B="A"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Still showing FILTER location number who is connected with B or C, not only with A.

Comment: @D.W not sure I understand you. pls explain

Comment: @D.W yes, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55008423/edit) to clarify it.

Comment: Maybe now I explained it better

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a list of all the locations

2) use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,VLOOKUP(E2,A:B,2))=COUNTIF(A:A,E2),"Unique","")
```

You will need to adjust cell references to match what you have. I had the locations in column `A` and the model in column `B`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is possible to combinate this formule with Unique to do auto list?